# Unity MVC GetService In Background Thread throws NullReferenceException

Tags: multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container, service-locator

As far as I know the DependencyResolver is Thread-Safe, however, running the following code throws a null reference exception in a background thread.

```
public interface ITest {

}
public class Test : ITest {

}

//this works fine
var service = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ITest>();

var t1 = Task.Run(() => {
   //This throws a Null Reference exception.
   // note that DependencyResolver.Current is NOT null.  
   // The exception occurs in GetService
   var s1 = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ITest>();
});
Task.WaitAll(t1);
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
at Unity.Mvc4.UnityDependencyResolver.get_ChildContainer()
at Unity.Mvc4.UnityDependencyResolver.IsRegistered(Type typeToCheck)
at Unity.Mvc4.UnityDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType)
at System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[TService](IDependencyResolver resolver)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I'm aware that the "Service Locator" pattern is an anti-pattern.  At this point I'm just trying to understand why this doesn't work.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Found this:   http://www.prowareness.com/blog/tag/nullreferenceexception/     So apparently asp.net mvc relies on HttpContext.Current, which is why this is not working in my MVC application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the stack trace it is clear that you are using the the [Unity.Mvc4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc4/) NuGet package, which is some unofficial package and is not published by Microsoft. This package contains a bug. Its `UnityDependencyResolver.ChildContainer` property calls `HttpContext.Current.Items` without checking whether `HttpContext.Current` is null and it causes a `NullReferenceException` when instances are resolved outside the context of a web request.

So instead of using that unofficial NuGet package, I think you're better off using the [official NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/).

Comment: +1 Fixed for me for an `async` MVC 5 method that called into `System.Web.MVC.ViewEngines`, which in turn uses Unity to inject its dependencies. Reproduced the error in .NET4.6.2 with Unity.MVC4 and Unity.MVC5. Moving to Unity.MVC (official Microsoft package) fixed the problem and required only namespace changes.